# Save call stack from Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I put a breakpoint and see a call stack in Chrome Dev Tools. Then, I want to change something in the code and see how call stack changes.

I wonder, if it's possible to somehow easily save current call stack as an object or a set of string so that to see the difference between two? It can be done by just making screenshots but seems not the best way, just in case there are no other variants.

Thanks!

Comment: Try right-click on log area in console tag and choose "Save as", you can save the all log as log file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can right click inside the call stack and press the 'copy stack trace' and paste it in any text editor.

Comment: Exactly! How did I miss it? Thanks!